# When suggested results display in our search box, we are unable to click through to the suggested product sku; how can we fix this?

Tags: css, templates, search-engine

```css
/* =============================================================================
   Global settings
   ========================================================================== */

article,
aside,
details,
figcaption,
figure,
footer,
header,
hgroup,
nav,
section {
  display: block;
}
audio,
canvas,
video {
  display: inline-block;
  *display: inline;
  *zoom: 1;
}
audio:not([controls]) {
  display: none;
}
[hidden] {
  display: none;
}
html {
  font-size: 100%;
  -webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%;
  -ms-text-size-adjust: 100%;
}
html,
button,
input,
select,
textarea {
  font-family: sans-serif;
  color: #222;
}
body {
  margin: 0;
  font-size: 1em;
  line-height: 1.4;
}
::-moz-selection {
  background: #fe57a1;
  color: #fff;
  text-shadow: none;
}
::selection {
  background: #fe57a1;
  color: #fff;
  text-shadow: none;
}
a {
  color: #00e;
}
a:visited {
  color: #551a8b;
}
a:hover {
  color: #06e;
}
a:focus {
  outline: thin dotted;
}
a:hover,
a:active {
  outline: 0;
}
abbr[title] {
  border-bottom: 1px dotted;
}
b,
strong {
  font-weight: bold;
}
blockquote {
  margin: 1em 40px;
}
dfn {
  font-style: italic;
}
hr {
  display: block;
  height: 1px;
  border: 0;
  border-top: 1px solid #ccc;
  margin: 1em 0;
  padding: 0;
}
ins {
  background: #ff9;
  color: #000;
  text-decoration: none;
}
mark {
  background: #ff0;
  color: #000;
  font-style: italic;
  font-weight: bold;
}
pre,
code,
kbd,
samp {
  font-family: monospace, serif;
  _font-family: 'courier new', monospace;
  font-size: 1em;
}
pre {
  white-space: pre;
  white-space: pre-wrap;
  word-wrap: break-word;
}
q {
  quotes: none;
}
q:before,
q:after {
  content: "";
  content: none;
}
small {
  font-size: 85%;
}
sub,
sup {
  font-size: 75%;
  line-height: 0;
  position: relative;
  vertical-align: baseline;
}
sup {
  top: -0.5em;
}
sub {
  bottom: -0.25em;
}
ul,
ol {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
dd {
  margin: 0 0 0 40px;
}
nav ul,
nav ol {
  list-style: none;
  list-style-image: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
img {
  border: 0;
  -ms-interpolation-mode: bicubic;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
svg:not(:root) {
  overflow: hidden;
}
figure {
  margin: 0;
}
form {
  margin: 0;
}
fieldset {
  border: 0;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
label {
  cursor: pointer;
}
legend {
  border: 0;
  *margin-left: -7px;
  padding: 0;
  white-space: normal;
}
button,
input,
select,
textarea {
  font-size: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  vertical-align: baseline;
  *vertical-align: middle;
}
button,
input {
  line-height: normal;
}
button,
input[type="button"],
input[type="reset"],
input[type="submit"] {
  cursor: pointer;
  -webkit-appearance: button;
  *overflow: visible;
}
button[disabled],
input[disabled] {
  cursor: default;
}
input[type="checkbox"],
input[type="radio"] {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 0;
  *width: 13px;
  *height: 13px;
}
input[type="search"] {
  -webkit-appearance: textfield;
  -moz-box-sizing: content-box;
  -webkit-box-sizing: content-box;
  box-sizing: content-box;
}
input[type="search"]::-webkit-search-decoration,
input[type="search"]::-webkit-search-cancel-button {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
}
button::-moz-focus-inner,
input::-moz-focus-inner {
  border: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
textarea {
  overflow: auto;
  vertical-align: top;
  resize: vertical;
}
input:valid,
textarea:valid {} input:invalid,
textarea:invalid {
  background-color: #f0dddd;
}
table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  border-spacing: 0;
}
td {
  vertical-align: top;
}
.chromeframe {
  margin: 0.2em 0;
  background: #ccc;
  color: black;
  padding: 0.2em 0;
}
.ir {
  display: block;
  border: 0;
  text-indent: -999em;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: transparent;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  text-align: left;
  direction: ltr;
  *line-height: 0;
}
.ir br {
  display: none;
}
.hidden {
  display: none !important;
  visibility: hidden;
}
.visuallyhidden {
  border: 0;
  clip: rect(0 0 0 0);
  height: 1px;
  margin: -1px;
  overflow: hidden;
  padding: 0;
  position: absolute;
  width: 1px;
}
.visuallyhidden.focusable:active,
.visuallyhidden.focusable:focus {
  clip: auto;
  height: auto;
  margin: 0;
  overflow: visible;
  position: static;
  width: auto;
}
.invisible {
  visibility: hidden;
}
.clearfix:before,
.clearfix:after {
  content: "";
  display: table;
}
.clearfix:after {
  clear: both;
}
.clearfix {
  *zoom: 1;
}
/* =============================================================================
   Fonts
   ========================================================================== */

/* =============================================================================
   Theme Global settings
   ========================================================================== */

#container {
  min-height: 100%;
}
.content {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  width: 1024px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
.nav_hover {
  background: #fff;
}
/* =============================================================================
   Header
   ========================================================================== */

header {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100px;
  background: url('../images/feral/header-bg.png') repeat-x;
}
header #logo {
  float: left;
  width: 33%;
  padding: 18px 0 0 0;
  margin-right: 25px;
}
/* =============================================================================
   Nav
   ========================================================================== */

nav {
  float: left;
  width: 33%px;
  height: 100px;
}
nav #site_tools {
  float: left;
  margin-left: 25px;
  margin-right: 50px;
}
nav #site_tools a {
  font-size: 14px;
  color: #fff;
  padding: 10px 10px 0 0;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-shadow: 0px 2px 1px #000;
}
nav #site_tools,
nav #display_search {
  padding: 10px 0 0 10px;
}
nav #display_search input[type=text] {
  width: 200px;
  height: 10px;
  font-size: 12px;
  font-weight: bold;
  padding: 10px;
  margin: 0;
}
nav #display_search input[type=submit] {
  width: 21px;
  height: 21px;
  background: url('../images/feral/search-icon.png') repeat-x;
  border: none;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0 0 0 5px;
}
#callus {
  padding-top: 10px;
}
#top_nav {
  height: 40px;
  background: #8e744f;
}
#top_nav #display_menu_1 {
  width: 1024px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
/* =============================================================================
   Body
   ========================================================================== */

#main {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  background: #f4f4f4;
  overflow: hidden;
}
#main #left_nav {
  width: 214px;
  background: #e5e4e4;
}
#main #left_nav h3 {
  height: 26px;
  font-size: 15px;
  color: #fff;
  background: #c2c0c0;
  padding: 6px 0 0 15px;
}
#main #left_nav #display_menu_2 a {
  color: #301f14;
}
#main #left_nav #display_menu_2 a:hover {
  color: #fff;
  background: #002284 left center no-repeat;
}
#main #content_area {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 6px 6px 15px 19px;
  text-align: left;
  width: 810px;
  background: #fff;
}
#main #div_articleid_1 ul,
#main #div_articleid_5 ul {
  margin-left: 0;
  padding-left: 18px;
}
#main #div_articleid_1,
#main #div_articleid_4,
#main #div_articleid_5 {
  line-height: 22px;
}
#main #div_articleid_4 strong {
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}
table ul {
  margin: 0 0 0 25px;
}
#slideshow {
  position: relative;
  height: 350px;
}
#slideshow A {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 15px;
  z-index: 8;
  opacity: 0.0;
}
#slideshow A.active {
  z-index: 10;
  opacity: 1.0;
}
#slideshow A.last-active {
  z-index: 9;
}
.special-products {
  margin: 0 0 0 40px;
}
/* =============================================================================
   Footer
   ========================================================================== */

footer {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  background: #575450;
  border-top: 4px solid #900101;
}
footer .content {
  height: 140px;
  padding-top: 30px;
}
footer .content .left,
footer .content .center,
footer .content .text {
  float: left;
  width: 18%;
}
footer .content .left {
  padding: 0 0 0 20px;
}
footer .content .center {
  width: 80%;
  font-size: 14px;
  color: #fff;
}
footer .content .center a {
  font-size: 14px;
  color: #fff;
}
footer .content .center ul,
footer .content .text ul {
  float: left;
}
footer .content .center ul {
  margin-left: 25px;
}
footer .content .center ul li,
footer .content .text ul li {
  list-style: none;
}
footer .content .center ul li.title {
  font-weight: bold;
}
footer .content .text {
  width: 100%;
  clear: both;
  text-align: center;
}
footer .content .text ul {
  float: none;
  margin: 40px 0 0 250px;
}
footer .content .text ul li {
  float: left;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 12px;
  margin-right: 15px;
}
/* =============================================================================
   Print
   ========================================================================== */

@media print {
  * {
    background: transparent !important;
    color: black !important;
    box-shadow: none !important;
    text-shadow: none !important;
    filter: none !important;
    -ms-filter: none !important;
  }
  a,
  a:visited {
    text-decoration: underline;
  }
  a[href]:after {
    content: " (" attr(href)")";
  }
  abbr[title]:after {
    content: " (" attr(title)")";
  }
  .ir a:after,
  a[href^="javascript:"]:after,
  a[href^="#"]:after {
    content: "";
  }
  pre,
  blockquote {
    border: 1px solid #999;
    page-break-inside: avoid;
  }
  thead {
    display: table-header-group;
  }
  tr,
  img {
    page-break-inside: avoid;
  }
  img {
    max-width: 100% !important;
  }
  @page {
    margin: 0.5cm;
  }
  p,
  h2,
  h3 {
    orphans: 3;
    widows: 3;
  }
  h2,
  h3 {
    page-break-after: avoid;
  }
}
.productnamecolorLARGE > span:nth-child(1) {
  font: 20px Arial;
}
```

This is our css template. I've been told there is something within the css that is interfering with a default function that would allow one to click on a drop-down suggestion from the search results and be redirected to the relevant page.

Comment: Here's a link to our website: http://www.mudsupply.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The links in the dropdown seem to work fine, you might be referring to the cursor.

Add
Located: jquery-ui.css line 101

`.ui-menu .ui-menu-item a{
    cursor: pointer !important;
    }`

or change

Located: jquery-ui.css line 69

```
.ui-autocomplete {
    cursor:pointer
}
```

Comment: sorry I'm not sure exactly where you're referring to in the css. Is it under the "global settings" area?

Comment: I added the file and line in my answer, it is being set by your jquery library

Comment: Thanks so much, since I have the css already posted here, I have one more question related to the Nav column on the left of our website's page. When you click on a "Category" is highlights that category blue, and it is supposed to make the text white (as it does when you hover over it). For some reason it doesn't work. Is this enough info to fix it?

Comment: Your css selector is being over rode by                          #main #left_nav #display_menu_2 a {
color: #301f14;
}   id attributes are more important than class attributes.  What you can do is in Navigation.css line 159, set color:#fff !important;

Comment: It is being over rode in Template.css line 115.